# Setting values whitout UI interaction. Cypress app actions

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress

Guys! I'm kinda new in cypress and was looking in this link (https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/01/03/stop-using-page-objects-and-start-using-app-actions/ )to see the diff between page objects and app actions. Since app actions are brand new, i was not able to find any documentation to help me out. In the link above, there was an example of how to predefine values ​​on the page so no UI interaction is required. I was able to follow the steps and realize the changes here, but i don't know how to do that outside this example.
How could i manipulate cypress application to do that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "without UI interaction". I would follow the put your selectors in your JS, if you have anything that is repeatable I would put that in a command..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skimming the article, the idea of *application actions* is to export an API/hooks from your application that your test can use to interact with the app (its model, state etc.), for the purpose of speeding up certain workflows (such as seeding the model), awaiting certain events etc.

There's nothing magical about it, but it requires knowing your app architecture — what you need to export (i.e. expose on the `window` object), and how to interact with it. If you're not the developer of the app (e.g. you work in a separate QA department), and treat the app as a black box, then you'll need to discuss with the dev team how best to implement this.

Each app is different, and depending on the app architecture (What framework does it use? How does it store state/model? etc.), each solution will be different.

Comment: Oh, i understand now, but in seeding the model scenario, i can only do that if i know the application architecture? If i'm new, and trying some other websites just to expand my knowledge, can't i do such things?

Comment: @Feronz not really, unless it exposes some API that you can tap into, but even then you'd need to know how their model works. This pattern is only meant for speeding up your tests, or making them easier to work with, when you have full access to the AUT (application under test) and can modify it.